# How to communicate between unrelated components in Angular 11?

Tags: angular

I have searched around for this and saw some examples using NgRx, but I don't want to use that on this small project I am working. I am hoping there is a simpler way.

### Goal

I am trying to update component b when component a is clicked. I am using Angular 11 and the components are not referencing one another. I'm also using Angular Material if that matters.

### Code

```html
<app-skills></app-skills>
<app-project></app-project>
```

app.component.html

SkillComponent is component b
ProjectComponent is component a

[image: ResumeApp1]

When the Skill chips on the ProjectComponent are clicked I want to update the Filter on the SkillComponent to filter the table to display that skill.

```html
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip *ngFor="let skillId of project.skillIds" (click)="filterSkill(skillId)"
    {{getSkill(skillId).skill}}
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

project.component.html

```js
filterSkill(id: number): void {
  console.log("filterSkill: id: ", id);
}
getSkill(id: number): Skill {
  return this.skillService.getById(id);
}
```

project.component.ts

```html
<mat-form-field id="skill-filter">
  <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
  <input matInput (keyup)="setFilter($event)" placeholder="e.g. aws" #input>
</mat-form-field>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
```

skill.component.html

```js
setFilter(event: Event) {
  const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

skill.component.ts

> Note: I'm using Angular Material Table for implementation: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#filtering

### Attempted

I've tried wiring the SkillComponent in the ProjectComponent constructor and calling the setFilter method directly, but that didn't work. Additionally, if that did work I wouldn't be able to display the changes in the HTML.

I've looked at @Input, yet unsure how to implement in this scenario since the components are not nesting one another.

### Conclusion

Hopefully you can help me resolve this issue or at least start moving in the right direction.

---

### Update

I tried to create a FilterService as suggested, but now the SkillComponent is not filtering anymore. My console loggers are firing on app load, but not when the value changes.

```js
constructor(private service: SkillService, private filter: FilterService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.filter.currentSearch$.subscribe(
    searchTerm => {
      console.log("searchTerm: ", searchTerm);
      this.dataSource.filter = searchTerm;
    },
    error => {
      console.log("error: ", error);
    },
    () => {
      console.log("complete!");
    }
  );
}

setFilter(event: Event) {
  const value = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.filter.setCurrentSearch(value);
  // this.dataSource.filter = value.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

skill.component.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {

  // public currentSearch$ : Observable<string> = of('');
  public currentSearch$ : BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

  constructor() {}

  public setCurrentSearch(searchTerm: string): void {
    // this.currentSearch$ = of(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase());
    this.currentSearch$ = new BehaviorSubject(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase());
  }
}
```

filter.service.ts

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is state management. As you mentioned, you could indeed use libraries like [ngrx](https://ngrx.io) to get a scalable and powerful solution, but to keep it simple, a service will be enough.
Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Create a service *FilterService*
2. Add a public observable *currentSearch$* in your service attributes
3. Inject *FilterService* in every component that is interacting with search terms
4. Each time the search terms change, call a method in *FilterService* that will trigger events in your observable
5. Each time a chip is clicked, call a method in *FilterService* too (it can be the same or a distinct one, depending on your architecture choices)
6. In each component that need to be updated with the terms, subscribe to *currentSearch$* and update the behavior accordingly.

**Update**

Based on the code you provided, the problem is in the *setCurrentSearch* method of your service. At this line :

```
this.currentSearch$ = new BehaviorSubject(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase());
```

you are replacing your BehavorSubject (to which your component has subscribed) with a new one (that no component is listening at all). To update your search terms, you must keep your BehaviorSubject intact, and only update its value. This is done like that:

```
this.currentSearch$.next(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this and accept the answer if it works for me.

Comment: You forgot to mention using Subject or BehaviorSubject for data sharing between components

Comment: Actually, I use to talk about observables as a generic term. BehaviorSubject and Subject are subclasses of Observable.

Comment: I'm having some issues implementing this. I updated my question to include the code I tried, which is not working. It'd be helpful if you could provide an example of this implementation. I'm not super familiar with Angular...

Comment: I just edited my answer with a reply to your second question.

Comment: Wicked awesome! That totally worked and was super simple to wire the FilterService in both components. Thanks a bunch.